# Passing argument from javascript to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using jqueryfiletree to display a folder of files on the web server. I also have php to parse the csv and display it on the page. How can I pass the selected jqueryfiletree file to the php in the page so it displays the selected csv? Here's what I have so far:

**Javscript:**

```
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqueryFileTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jqueryFileTree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#fileTreeDemo_1').fileTree({ root: '../data/', script:     
'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php' }, function(file) { 
                alert(file);
                var file = "<?php echo $file;?>";

            });

        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Select a file to view</h1>
    <div class="menuleftcontent">
        <div id="fileTreeDemo_1" class="demo"></div>
    </div>
</td><td>
```

**PHP**

```
    <div class="maincontent">
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

echo '<table border="1">';

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
fclose($handle);
}
?>     
 </div>
```

Comment: does everything work up until the javascript alert?

Comment: Send an AJAX request to the server with the information, then receive it using a PHP script, and deal with it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems so far. Firstly, you do not have a semi-colon to end the line on this line:

```
var file = "<?php echo $file;?>";
```

(i've added it).

Also, $file is not defined in your php. And you can not try and define it in javascript (I fear that is what you are trying to do maybe?).

Best options is to make an AJAX request so you can send it to the server side and use it there (which is what you want?). And of course, you can then respond data back to the front end.

THis is a rough idea:

```
            $('#fileTreeDemo_1').fileTree({ root: '../data/', script:     
'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php' }, function(file) { 
              $.post('myphpfile.php', {file:file}, function(response){
                    // handle response
              });

            });
```

and then in php, check for the post with `if(isset($_POST['file']))` ,etc etc

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed both of those issue. I'm not familiar with ajax. Any suggestions on how i could do this?

Comment: Thanks again for the help! So I should take the PHP part out and put it in a separate page called myphpfile.php and add the isset if statement to the top? How do I know what variable to read in the php page?